# Why does this list index go out of range?

Tags: python

I'm taking some baby steps with pygame, and I have gotten this program to work. However it throws a "List index out of range" message after looping through main() several hundred times. The list doesn't change size once it grows to a certain limit, so I am not sure where the error is happening.

Once you run the program, just move the mouse across the display, and a bunch of circles are drawn and grow as the clock ticks. Eventually, it will crash.

I have omitted all comments except the lines where the error is happening, hopefully that will make it easier to find out the cause.

Stacktrace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Devo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\test files\Psychedelic Circles.py", line 89, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Devo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\test files\Psychedelic Circles.py", line 49, in main
    drawCircles(snakeLength)
  File "C:\Users\Devo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\test files\Psychedelic Circles.py", line 75, in drawCircles
    pygame.draw.circle(SCREEN, colorList[i], coords[i], abs(i-(len(coords))) * 5, 0)#### Why does the list index go out of range?
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
     import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import*
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
FUSCHIA = (255,   0, 240)
GRAY = (80, 80, 80)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 127, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
INDIGO = (75, 0, 130)
VIOLET = (148, 0, 211)

FPS = 20
WWIDTH  = 1000
WHEIGHT = 700


BIGBUTTON = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 1000, 700)
rainbowTuple = (RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, INDIGO, VIOLET)


def main():
    global SCREEN, FPS, colorList, coords, snakeLength
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    size = (WWIDTH, WHEIGHT)    
    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(size)    
    pygame.display.set_caption('Psychedelic Circles')   
    colorList = []
    coords = []
    snakeLength = 50 ### Change this value to make the circles disappear more   quickly or slowly
    while True:
        clickedButton = None
        SCREEN.fill(GRAY)
        drawButtons()
        checkForQuit()        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION: 
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
                clickedButton = getButtonClicked(mousex, mousey)
                if clickedButton == FUSCHIA:
                    sendCoords(mousex, mousey)

        drawCircles(snakeLength)        

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def sendCoords(x, y):
    coords.append((x, y))
    colorList.append(random.choice(rainbowTuple))

def checkForQuit():
    for event in pygame.event.get(QUIT):
        terminate()
    for event in pygame.event.get(KEYUP):
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            terminate()
        pygame.event.post(event)

def drawButtons():
    pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, FUSCHIA, BIGBUTTON)

def drawCircles(snakeLength):
    for i in range(len(coords)):
        pygame.draw.circle(SCREEN, colorList[i], coords[i], abs(i-(len(coords))) * 5, 0)#### Why does the list index go out of range?
        if i > snakeLength :   
            popList()

def popList():
    coords.pop(0)
    colorList.pop(0)

def getButtonClicked(x, y):
    if BIGBUTTON.collidepoint((x, y)):
        return FUSCHIA
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: please post the stacktrace also to show where the exception is triggered.

Comment: Just keep the relevant code here and as mentioned in above comment post stacktrace

Comment: We need more information, as required above, but first I'm not sure naming your functions' parameters the exact same way as your global variables is a good idea. The induced behavior is probably defined but that's a potential source of errors.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, it's a bad idea to change the size of a list while inside a loop that's iterating over that list. Try to refactor `drawCircles` so that it doesn't call `popList` until after the loop is complete.

Comment: `len(coords)` will change if `popList` is called but `range(len(coords))` is not recalculated.  Leaving with a range that is longer than `coords`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try rewriting the functions and see if it works. Any ideas why it will loop through main() several hundred times before the error gets thrown? Also, I added a print(len(coords)) at the end of the while loop, and it always shows the same number, so if the list length doesn't change, then how can the index be out of range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this error only occurs when there are multiple mouse move events in the event queue. Normally, pygame is fast enough to render the screen while accruing no more than one new user input event, so `sendCoords` will only be called once in between `drawCircles` calls. In that case, `coords` never exceeds a size of 52. But if several mouse move events accrue (perhaps due to system lag, or because the user is jiggling his mouse really fast), then `sendCoords` may be called many more times in a row. So by the time `drawCircles` executes, `coords` can have 53 elements, or even more.

This becomes a problem when you reach `drawCircles`:

```
def drawCircles(snakeLength):
    for i in range(len(coords)):
        pygame.draw.circle(SCREEN, colorList[i], coords[i], abs(i-(len(coords))) * 5, 0)#### Why does the list index go out of range?
        if i > snakeLength :   
            popList()
```

Let's say this function executes when `coords` contains 53 elements, and `snakeLength` is 50. The loop will iterate normally until `i` equals 51. Then the `i > snakeLength` will evaluate to True, and `popList` will be called. Now `coords` is one element smaller, and has a length of 52. That iteration of the loop ends, and the next iteration starts. `i` will equal 52. The `pygame.draw.circle` line will attempt to access `coords[i]`, but because `coords` no longer has 53 elements, `coords[i]` will raise an IndexError trying to access the 53rd element.

Python is not smart enough to understand that the `for i in range(len(coords))` loop should end one iteration earlier than usual if `coords` reduces in size by one. It happily iterates all the way up to the original length of the list, heedless of whether this might cause a crash.

One possible solution is to move `popList` outside of the list, so the size of `coords` doesn't change while you're iterating over it.

```
def drawCircles(snakeLength):
    for i in range(len(coords)):
        pygame.draw.circle(SCREEN, colorList[i], coords[i], abs(i-(len(coords))) * 5, 0)#### Why does the list index go out of range?

    while len(coords) > snakeLength :   
        popList()
```

You might be thinking "But  why is it OK to modify `coords`' length in this while loop, when it wasn't OK to do it in the for loop?" The critical distinction is the evaluation time of the two statements. `range(len(coords))` exectues exactly once before the loop starts, so modifications to `coords` won't be noticed. but `len(coords) > snakeLength` executes at the beginning of very iteration of the while loop, so changes to `coords` gets noticed right away.

Comment: You've given me a lot to chew on . Thanks for taking the time, I appreciate it.